# React/Redux - I delete an item out of 6 total, when re-render happens it appends the old list(6) onto the new list(5) now I have 11 items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

Initially what I'm trying to do is attach the the deleteItem event to every book-item. I have an action 'DELETE_BOOK' that accepts the id of the book-item and then in the reducers it return the book list without the book-item that I specified to be deleted. The item gets deleted but for some reason it appends the old list (6 items) onto the new list(5 items after deletion) and now I end up with 11 items.

[Entire project source code](https://github.com/denorro/fullstack-react-bookstore)

```
//book-list.js    
"use strict"    
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {getBooks, deleteBook} from '../../actions/booksActions';
import BookItem from './book-item';
import BookForm from './book-form';
import Cart from './cart';

class BookList extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.deleteBookItem = this.deleteBookItem.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
       this.props.getBooks();
    }

    deleteBookItem(_id){
        this.props.deleteBook(_id);
    }

    render(){        
        const bookList = this.props.books.map(function(book){
            return (
                <BookItem 
                    key={book._id}
                    _id={book._id}
                    title={book.title}
                    description={book.description}
                    price={book.price} 
                    deleteBookItem={this.deleteBookItem}
                />
            )
        }, this);

        return(
            <div>
                <div className="page-header">
                    <h1 className="text-center">The React BookStore</h1>
                </div>
                { this.props.msg &&
                    <div className="alert alert-info text-center" 
                    role="alert">{this.props.msg}</div>
                }                
                <Cart />                
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                        <div className="row">
                            {bookList}
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                       <BookForm />
                    </div>
                </div>                               
            </div>
        )
    }
}

//just return the data from the store
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {        
        books: state.books.books,
        msg: state.books.msg
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({
        getBooks: getBooks,
        deleteBook: deleteBook
    }
    , dispatch);
}
//connects component to the store
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookList);

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//book-item.js
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {addToCart, updateCart} from '../../actions/cartActions';

class BookItem extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.deleteBookItem = this.deleteBookItem.bind(this);
    }

    deleteBookItem(){
        const index = this.props._id;
        this.props.deleteBookItem(index);
    }

    handleCart = () => {
        const book = [...this.props.cart, {
            _id: this.props._id,
            title: this.props.title,
            description: this.props.description,
            price: this.props.price,
            qty: 1
        }];
        if(this.props.cart.length > 0){
            let _id = this.props._id;
            let cartIndex = this.props.cart.findIndex(function(cart){
                return cart._id === _id;
            });
            if(cartIndex === -1){
                this.props.addToCart(book);
            }
            else{
                this.props.updateCart(_id, 1);
            }
        }
        else {
            this.props.addToCart(book);
        }        
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-6" key={this.props._id}>
                <div className="well">
                    <h2 className="text-center">{this.props.title}</h2>
                    <h2 className="text-center">{this.props.description}
                    </h2>
                    <h2 className="text-center">{this.props.price}</h2>
                    <button className="btn btn-success btn-block" onClick=
                    {this.handleCart}>
                        <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart">
                        </i>
                        <span> Add To Cart</span>
                    </button>
                    <button className="btn btn-danger btn-block" onClick=
                    {this.deleteBookItem}>
                        <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                        <span> Delete Book</span>
                    </button>
                </div>                    
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        cart: state.cart.cart
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators(
        {
            addToCart: addToCart,
            updateCart: updateCart,
        }
        , dispatch);
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookItem);

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

//bookActions.js
"use strict"

export function getBooks(){
    return {
        type: 'GET_BOOKS'
    }
}

export function postBook(book){
    return {
        type: 'POST_BOOK', 
        payload: book
    }
}

export function deleteBook(_id){
    return {
        type: 'DELETE_BOOK', 
        payload: _id
    }
}

export function updateBook(book){
    return {
        type: 'UPDATE_BOOK', 
        payload: book
    }
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//booksReducers.js
"use strict"
//BOOKS REDUCERS
let defaultBooks = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    title: 'Book 1',
    description: 'Book 1 Description',
    price: 19.99
  },
  {
      _id: 2,
      title: 'Book 2',
      description: 'Book 2 Description',
      price: 29.99  
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    title: 'Book 3',
    description: 'Book 3 Description',
    price: 39.99
  },
  {
      _id: 4,
      title: 'Book 4',
      description: 'Book 4 Description',
      price: 49.99  
  },
  {
    _id: 5,
    title: 'Book 5',
    description: 'Book 5 Description',
    price: 59.99
  },
  {
      _id: 6,
      title: 'Book 6',
      description: 'Book 6 Description',
      price: 69.99  
  }
];
export function booksReducers(state = { books: defaultBooks }, action){

  switch(action.type){
    case "GET_BOOKS":
        return {...state, books:[...state.books]}
        break;
    case "POST_BOOK":
        return {...state, books:[...state.books, ...action.payload], 
       msg:'Saved! Click to continue', style:'success', 
       validation:'success'}
        break;
    case "POST_BOOK_REJECTED":
        return {...state, msg:'Please, try again', style:'danger', 
        validation:'error'}
        break;
    case "RESET_BUTTON":
        return {...state, msg:null, style:'primary', validation:null}
        break;
    case "DELETE_BOOK":
        // Create a copy of the current array of books
        const currentBookToDelete = [...state.books];
        // Determine at which index in books array is the book to be deleted
        const indexToDelete = currentBookToDelete.findIndex(function(book){
          return book._id === action.payload._id;
        });
        //use slice to remove the book at the specified index
        return {books: [...currentBookToDelete.slice(0, indexToDelete), 
        ...currentBookToDelete.slice(indexToDelete + 1)]}
        break;

    case "UPDATE_BOOK":
        // Create a copy of the current array of books
        const currentBookToUpdate = [...state.books]
        // Determine at which index in books array is the book to be deleted
        const indexToUpdate = currentBookToUpdate.findIndex(
          function(book){
            return book._id === action.payload._id;
          }
        )
        // Create a new book object with the new values and with the same 
      array index of the item we want to replace. To achieve this we will 
      use ...spread but we could use concat methos too
        const newBookToUpdate = {
          ...currentBookToUpdate[indexToUpdate],
          title: action.payload.title
        }
        // Log has the purpose to show you how newBookToUpdate looks like
        console.log("what is it newBookToUpdate", newBookToUpdate);
        //use slice to remove the book at the specified index, replace with 
        the new object and concatenate witht he rest of items in the array
        return {
          books: [...currentBookToUpdate.slice(0, indexToUpdate), 
          newBookToUpdate, ...currentBookToUpdate.slice(indexToUpdate + 1)]
        }
        break;
        default:
        break;
  }
  return state
}

[enter code here][1]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCTyr.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a filter function? Check if it's working with this:

```
case "DELETE_BOOK":
    const bookId = action.payload._id;
    return {books: state.books.filter(book => book._id !== bookId}
```

And you don't need break after returns in switch statement.

Comment: Yea I was following a tutorial where this bookReducer code comes from and that's why I was using the findIndex way. But I'm trying to deviate away from the tutorial a little bit on the front end because the tutorial was deleting them using a dropdown and submit, but I wanted to attach the delete functionality right at the button level. But let me your way instead.

Comment: Could you post the link to the tutorial please?

Comment: [Full stack Universal React with Redux, Node js and MongoDB](https://www.udemy.com/full-stack-universal-react-with-redux-express-and-mongodb/?src=sac&kw=full)

Comment: YES! Your solutions worked! The only thing I had to do different was to take off the '_id' off of payload. `